# Where manifest sharedUserLabel is visible to user?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am setting up `sharedUserLabel` in the manifest of my app for some case. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uidlabel) tells that

> A user-readable label for the shared user ID

So where the user is able to view this label? I did not get this. Please clear.

Comment: @NileshRathod Sorry, It is not about that, it is sharedUserLabel.

Comment: check this [What is android:sharedUserLabel and what added value does it add on top of android:sharedUserID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9856388/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks, this answer is useful. However I could not get where `sharedUserLabel` is shown. or this answer has not clearly mentioned it.